# r-exams: 'Meta-information' warnings in fully automated question generation: can they be removed? Are they important? (code works fine)

Tags: r, r-exams

I'm writing some code to automate as much as possible the process of generating questions. This involves building the question inside the r code part of the file. A MWE to illustrate the scenario can be the following:

````
```{r}

example <- paste0(
   "Question\n========\n\nHello!"
 , "\n##ANSWER1##  ##ANSWER2##"
 , "\n\nSolution\n========"
 , "\n* Sol1\n* Sol2"
 , "\n\nMeta-information\n================"
 , "\nexname: test"
 , "\nextype: cloze"
 , "\nexsolution: SOL1|SOL2"
 , "\nexclozetype: string|string"
)

cat("exercise:\n", example, sep='', file=stderr())

```

`r example`
````

After putting this code in the file "test.Rmd", the following command in RStudio:

```
exams2moodle("test.Rmd")
```

yields this warning output:

```
Warning messages:
1: In extract_command(x, "extype", markup = markup) :
  command‘extype:’occurs more than once, last instance used
2: In extract_command(x, "exname", markup = markup) :
  command‘exname:’occurs more than once, last instance used
3: In extract_command(x, "exsolution", markup = markup) :
  command‘exsolution:’occurs more than once, last instance used
4: In extract_command(x, "exclozetype", markup = markup) :
  command‘exclozetype:’occurs more than once, last instance used
```

The code works fine, as stated in the title. Although I don't fully understand the meaning of the following header (I couldn't find any documentation in the r-exams web), I am aware that putting it at the very beginning of the `test.Rmd` file instead of the  ```` ```{r} ```` simple one removes the warning output (you can control whether warnings are shown using the `echo = <BOOLEAN>` parameter):

````
```{r data generation, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
````

So the question is:

1. Should I be concerned about these warnings, or can they be just ignored?

In addition, and related to this:

2. Is the header format meant to deal with cases like this (among other uses)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly identified the source of the problem: Your  ```` ```{r} ```` code chunk is not only evaluated (to create the `example` variable) but it is also printed verbatim into the resulting Markdown file. And then the package is confused that `extype` etc. occur twice in the document: once in the verbatim code chunk and once in the meta-information section. The former is ignored though and only the latter used, hence the exercise works correctly.

So the alternative would be to use the extended code chunk header that you indicated:

````
```{r data generation, echo = FALSE, results = "hide"}
````

This gives the code chunk a label ("data generation") which is entirely optional, suppresses the code input (`echo = FALSE` which is the important bit here), and suppresses any output (which there is none of here anyway).

A shorter declaration that would also do the trick is

````
```{r, include = FALSE}
````

If you want to check what goes into the .md file after processing the .Rmd file try

```
xweave("test.Rmd")
```

and then inspect the resulting `test.md`.

Having said that, the `extype` etc. outside of the `Meta-information` should really be ignored. Currently, this is apparently not done because some infrastructure is shared with the .Rnw reader which does not have an explicit `{metainformation}` environment. I will have a look at a potential fix, though.

Comment: Then, after playing with different header values and inspecting `xweave`'s corresponding output files (which is kind of a generation intermediate step in the whole process of the final `.xml` file generation, I guess), I don't want to print the code into it (this will confuse the 'interpretation' step); I only want its evaluation result in order to get a 'clean' `.md` file. Thank you very much. You've been very helpful!

Comment: Yes, exactly. The steps are: _1. Weave_ (Rmd to md), _2. Read_ (md into an R list), _3. Transform_ (e.g., Markdown to HTML), _4. Write_ (e.g., insert HTML into suitable Moodle XML and write .xml file). For more details on the design of the software, see https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v058.i01 (even though a lot of details have changed since then).

Comment: I have also improved the package to avoid the confusion in the _2. Read_ step when `extype` etc. occur outside of the `Meta-information`. If you install the devel version from R-Forge (2.4-1 at the moment), then your original `test.Rmd` runs correctly without warning. Run: `install.packages("exams", repos = "https://R-Forge.R-project.org")`